# Higher optimization slowdown the function (Fortran)

Tags: performance, optimization, fortran, gfortran

Consider the following function for taking dot product of a matrix column with a vector to yield new vector:

```
    subroutine smxv(a, x, y, n)
        !y = a*x
        use iso_fortran_env
        implicit none
        integer (int32)   :: n
        real (real64)     :: a(:,:), x(:), y(:)
        integer (int32)   :: i
        y=0
        do i = 1, n
          y(i) =  dot_product(a(:,i),x)
        end do
    end subroutine smxv
```

When I optimize it with `-O2` compiler flag my average execution time (averaged over 10 runs) is approximately 31 seconds. When I compile it with `-O2 -march=native` flag my avg. execution time goes up to 47 seconds.

I am not sure why it should go up? At worst, should it not remain same?

I tried looking at hotspots in VTune and it shows that after adding `-march=native` that move and add instructions takes most time, while otherwise it is multiply and jmp? Is there any rationale why I would get such timings?

[image: Timing compare O2 vs O2 march=native]

Side note: if I change the function to explicitly include array size in the definition
`real (real64)     :: a(n,n), x(n), y(n)`,
then overall timing remains the same, but individual timing changes.

With `-O2`:

```
0x401300  Block 12:            
0x401300  movsdq  0x8(%rcx,%rax,1), %xmm0   0.0%     0.010s
0x401306  mulsdq  (%rbx,%rax,1), %xmm0      9.6%     3.014s
0x40130b  add $0x8, %rax                    0.3%     0.090s
0x40130f  cmp %rax, %rdx                    29.8%    9.366s
0x401312  addsd %xmm0, %xmm1            
0x401316  jnz 0x401300 <Block 12>           59.2%   18.629s
```

With `-O2 -march=native`:

```
0x4012f0  Block 12:    
0x4012f0  vmovsdq  0x8(%rcx,%rax,1), %xmm2               0.3%   0.151s
0x4012f6  vfmadd231sdq  (%rbx,%rax,1), %xmm2, %xmm0      5.0%   2.387s
0x4012fc  add $0x8, %rax                                93.8%   44.490s
0x401300  cmp %rax, %rdx                                 0.0%   0.020s
0x401303  jnz 0x4012f0 <Block 12>
```

If that gives any clue.

```
Compiler: GNU GFORTRAN 7.3.1
OS:       CentOS 7.3.16
CPU:      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
```

Comment: Does Y(i) ever become anything other than DOT_PRODUCT(A(N,i)*X(i))? Or should there be some accumulation into Y(i)?

Comment: Not addressing your question really, but is there a good reason why you aren't using dgemv from blas for this?

Comment: It would also be useful to have an idea of how big N is

Comment: @Holmz y remains untouched after this and is only added or multiplied with other vectors

Comment: If so why zero it before the loop?

Comment: @IanBush Nis currently only 8k , but hoping to take till 100000. Reason to do it over dgemv is that scalapack pdgemv is distributed memory and lapack dgemv was single threaded (right?). SO i figured I can write more performant function by using openMP. As my matrix will aways be symmetric I can use colum in vector instead row into vector and get same results. Above function was just single thread benchmark to see how it fares

Comment: Sorry, 0 was just force of habit.

Comment: Most dgemv's are threaded nowadays - mkl or openblas are, the latter is free https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/User-Manual. The only single threaded BLAS I can think of is the reference one, which you shouldn't be using in production.

Comment: mkl i wanted avoid. but thanks for openblas suggestion. i was not aware its threaded. I would still like to know in which case higher optimization degrade performance. i saw a commnet on intel user forums that higher optimizations can degrade performance in some cases, but no example or reason was provided. (https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/O3-optimizations-make-the-code-slower/td-p/1125009)

Comment: Last comment - you can get mkl for free as well at the moment, but I do appreciate not wanting to de dependent upon Intel's current thoughts on licensing

Comment: What is happening on that y(i) =  dot_product(a(:,i),x)? Is he right side returning a vector?

Comment: I am sorry I did no understand. dot_product returns a scalar